# WebMethod call results in OutOfMemoryException on client. Can results be written directly to hard drive?

Tags: .net, web-services, out-of-memory

I'm calling a WebMethod on a .net Web Service. It can pull in enough data to cause an OutOfMemoryException on the client, because it is overwhelming the 2GB limit a Windows process is allowed.

Because of a deadline, I don't want to solve this by adding code to split the calls into smaller chunks. I can use the LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag on the client, but the client's process will still have a limit (3GB-4GB). At this point, I can only say that this would be better, but I can't say that will forever be enough (the client is a WinForm that will be released to customers on a CD, so I only get one shot at this).

What would be excellent would be a way of calling the WebMethod and having the method's results written directly to a file on the hard drive instead of being written to variables in my .NET code. I could then read the file one memory-friendly chunk at a time from the file. From what I can tell, Web Services doesn't have a way to do this.

Is there any way to do this with Web Services? Are there any other creative solutions you can think up to solve my OOM problem?

Comment: What does the declaration of your `WebMethod` look like?

Comment: public MyStruct[] MyWebMethod(string, string)

Comment: MyStruct contains a string which has the bulk of the data that causes the OOME.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said which disk you'd like to write to. You could conceivably write the output to a folder on the service, and expose the folder through a file share. Your service would then return the path to the (temporary) file on the server back to the client.

I presume you're talking about a legacy ASMX service? They have problems with the serialization creating multiple copies of the request and response messages. Try using "Add Service Reference" on the client instead of "Add Web Reference".